# Safari in iPhone - The file object selected using <input type="file"> reference is lost/cleared if left idle for more than ~40s

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari

I have a webpage where there is an option to select the file from the file system using `<input type="file">`

If the upload process is started immediately the file gets successfully uploaded. If after selecting the file the user leaves it idle for some time(30 - 40 seconds) and then uploads the file reference is lost and gets uploaded as 0 bytes.

My use-case is after selecting the file few things has to be done before clicking on upload in that time
the reference gets lost.

Any solution to overcome this problem?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.. did you have any workaround for now